# How to extend class name with condition in React?

Tags: reactjs

So I want to extend a `div`'s classname using conditions. What I have is something like

```
className={`orignClassName ${this.state.something === 'something' ? 'extendClassName1' : 'ExtendClassName2'}
```

But it did not seem to work. Can someone tell me what would be the correct way to do it? Thank you!

Comment: Have a look at classnames npm package => https://www.npmjs.com/package/classnames. It nicely solves the issue you are facing.

Comment: You can use `cslx` or `classnames` npm library. It is the established practice in React.

Comment: Is there a way without using cslx or npm library? Just curiosity.

Comment: @mangochips I gave you one. There is absolutely no need to use a package for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply put it in an array :

`<div className={['class1', variable, 'class2'].join(' ')}>A super div</div>`

([MDN Doc about `join()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join))

Here is a [repro on StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-functional-boilerplate-16-13-1-xlmuxm?file=style.css) and here is the code :

```js
import React from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import './style.css';

const App = () => {
  const [condition, setCondition] = React.useState(false);

  return (
    <>
      <div className={['bg-red', condition ? 'text-white' : ''].join(' ')}>This is a template react</div>
      <button onClick={() => setCondition(!condition)}>Switch condition</button>
    </>
  );
};

render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```css
.bg-red {
  background-color: red;
}

.text-white {
  color: white;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The more well format way is using [`clsx`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/clsx).

Comment: Or [classnames](https://www.npmjs.com/package/classnames)